# Is there a way in Silverlight to compress the video from webcam before it is saved?

Tags: silverlight, video-capture, video-encoding

We are capturing some video from a webcam in Silverlight, and I'm looking forward for a solution to encode the video real-time before it is getting saved, so that the file size is not bloated up too much. Is there an already available solution, or whether we've to write some custom codecs?

Answer (score 2):

from a codec point, I found a open source project. http://silverlightencoder.codeplex.com/.
Please verify.

Comment: One major issue with this lib is it uses COM at client side which is in general not advisable.